# Recover Windows boot partition

Tags: windows, boot, recovery

I'm on a multiboot PC with Ubuntu and Win10 (pre-installed)

While playing around with bootable sticks etc. I accidentally formatted the Win boot partition on /dev/sda1 (524MB) and thus lost access to my Windows system. (grub doesn't list it any more)
Fortunately my user data and the recovery partition still exists and should be unharmed

My target is now to recreate the boot partition so that I can boot Windows again without modifying the user-data partition obviously.

I already have a bootable win10 stick and tried to repair the boot sector without luck (the automated option and with cmd following [this guide](https://www.diskpart.com/windows-10/accidentally-deleted-boot-partition-windows-10.html))
Unfortunately I couldn't try AOMEI yet because after installing in wine the program says 'load driver failed' and I didn't look into this any further.

The cmd following 2.2 of the guide resulted into 'permission denied' when trying to execute `bootrec /fixboot`. Stopped at this point as well.

Third option could be to copy a boot sector from an other working Win10 setup but I didn't have access to one yet.

So can anyone show me how to safely restore this boot sector?

Comment: There is a canonical question at Ask Ubuntu for this: https://askubuntu.com/q/217904. An Ubuntu install can be in either BIOS mode or UEFI mode, whichever one works. After the installation is complete it can be converted either way from BIOS mode to UEFI mode or in the opposite direction from UEFI mode to BIOS mode, so that both Windows and Ubuntu are the same boot mode: https://askubuntu.com/a/952952/. That way both Windows and Ubuntu are able to boot from the same bootloader.

Comment: It helps me too because there is a new type of device (NVMe SSD) that has been reported as having bootloader problems. Some of my answers at Ask Ubuntu need to be updated for this category of device, and I haven't finished updating all of them yet. I updated one of them a few minutes ago. For this reason if the comments on this question exceed the maximum amount I will create a chatroom for just this question which supports an unlimited number of comments + screenshots.

Comment: I tried the boot-repair tool you mentioned in the other thread but it resulted in an error message stating that it is compressed or smth. I looked at the partition in linux and it only contained a Temp folder with some logs and disk info which looks like debug outputs from boot-repair

PS: sorry to dissapoint you but I neither have an SSD nor UEFI mode but a regular BIOS setup
and from what I read [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/56958) one cannot switch between bios and uefi that easily
Also I'd like to stick to bios at least until I can boot Windows and make a backup again

Comment: could it be that this partition I am referring to is this 'cryptic partition' mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1066177)? For me has a size of 500MB.
guess its the [bcd](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-rebuild-the-bcd-in-windows-2624508)

Comment: In Ubuntu this partition is called the EFI System Partition. The EFI System Partition (ESP) is a partition on a data storage device (usually an HDD or SSD) that is used by the computer to boot OSs. It's like a step that is taken before it runs the Windows partition. It's a small partition, but without that partition your computer wouldn't know how to boot Windows.The ESP ranges in size from 100MB-500MB, is usually located at beginning of the drive so that BIOS/UEFI can easily find it, and is formatted as FAT32.

Comment: so how do I recover it? Just a FAT formatted partition won't be enough obviously.
In the end update-grub has to detect the Windows partition for booting

Comment: A 100MB-500MB FAT formatted partition is all that Boot-Repair needs. Boot-Repair will install grub to this ESP partition by default if one already exists. If no ESP partition exists Boot-Repair will create one on UEFI systems.

Comment: Open the Boot Repair application and select *Advanced Options* -> *Other Options* tab -> *Repair Windows boot files* ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpG7x.png)). The boot flag should be placed on the same partition on which Ubuntu is installed. The partition on which Ubuntu is installed can be identified from the Disks application which is built-in in Ubuntu.

Comment: the 'repair windows boot files' checkbox was greyed out. Thus I tried the recommended repair option. However the grub.cfg still doesn't contain windows. Only a windows recovery environment on sda2 which contains my user data and also a /boot and a /boot-repair dir which weren't there before. Unfortunately it seems this had no effect to grub

Comment: [Is it possible to boot Ubuntu using the Windows bootloader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've solved the problem partially

I went into the Windows recovery cmd and executed `bcdboot E:\Windows /s C:` where
E: is my User-Partition and
C: is my boot partition

Then I went into rescatux (any (Linux) OS with grub is possible) and ran update-grub according to https://askubuntu.com/questions/145241

This finally made Windows reappear in the grub menu

thanks karel for your support - it helped me alot to understand some basics and some things I might consider to do in the future :)

Edit:

At this point I can't exactly remember what I've done to make it work but I'll try to reflect as good as possible:

I re-formatted the boot partition (500MB) to Fat32 as before. After that I ran a comination of bootrec commands (fixmbr, fixboot and rebuildbcd)
(note that at this point the grub installation has been overridden by fixmbr)

finally the bcdboot command with an additional `/f UEFI` option did the trick and after *re-installing and updating grub* on the *sda* partition my Windows system was finally bootable again.

This was hell of a bottleneck but I'm glad it worked :)

Comment: turns out the bootmgr still doesn't like it
When trying to boot windows a message _'This is not a bootable disk. please insert a bootable floppy and press any key to try again'_ appears

Comment: looks like some files in the E:Windows dir are corrupt. At least I get io errors for some files when trying to ls the dir from linux

Comment: Finally got it working. see my edit in the answer above